# How to format currency value from another class - Java

Tags: java, format

How can I format the order Total in the Business class from the Program class.
Thanks.

The Business class:

```
public class Business
{

    private int numberOfTickets;
    private int ticketType;

    Business()
    {
        int numberOfTickets = 0;
        int ticketType = 0;
    }

    Business(int numberOfTickets, int ticketType)
    {
        this.numberOfTickets = numberOfTickets;
        this.ticketType = ticketType;
    }

    public void setNumberOfTickets(int numberOfTickets)
    {
        this.numberOfTickets = numberOfTickets;
    }
    public int getNumberOfTickets()
    {
        return numberOfTickets;
    }

    public void setTicketType(int ticketType)
    {
        this.ticketType = ticketType;
    }
    public int getTicketType()
    {
        return ticketType;
    }

    // static method for calculations
    public static double orderTotal(double ticketType, int numberOfTickets)
    {

        //price of tickets
        if (ticketType == 1)
        {
            ticketType = 64.00;
        }
        else if (ticketType == 2)
        {
            ticketType = 54.00;
        }
        else if (ticketType == 3)
        {
            ticketType = 44.00;
        }
        else
        {

        }

        double fees;
        return fees = ticketType * numberOfTickets;
    }
}
```

The Program Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Program
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Business business1 = new Business();        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            // asks for user information                
            System.out.print("Enter the number of tickets: ");
            int numberOfTickets = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            business1.setNumberOfTickets(numberOfTickets);

            System.out.print("Enter the ticket type: ");
            int ticketType = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            business1.setTicketType(ticketType);
```

This is where I wanted to format the total, using the orderTotal static method from the Business class.

```
            NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
            double orderTotal = 0.00;
            orderTotal = double.parseDouble(orderTotal);

            //calling the methods:
            System.out.println(nNumber of tickets: " + business1.getNumberOfTickets()
            + "\nTicket type: " + business1.getTicketType()
            + "\nOrder Total = " + Business.orderTotal(ticketType, numberOfTickets));
    }
}
```

Comment: But I can't get it to work, because _______ (please fill in the blanks). What's happening instead? Do you get an exception? Does your code even compile?

Comment: It compiles but has errors, and the total is still not formatted.

Comment: Errors, such as _______ and the total is still not formatted, but instead ______. Let's try this again, my glass sphere is currently broken :)

Comment: Are you trying to format the value returned, maybe to include only two digits after the decimal?

Comment: all 4 errors are related to double.parseDouble(orderTotal); 1st error says collon is required. 2nd error says its not an statement, and the other 2 are same as the first.

Comment: Why did you write `orderTotal = double.parseDouble(orderTotal);` ? It's already a double. It makes no sense to parse a double into a double. It's **already** a double. Use your `currency` NumberFormat that you created to make the double into a String instead.

Comment: `double.anything` won't even compile, because `double` is not an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a format such as $XXX.xx then use

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
...
double orderTotalDbl = Business.orderTotal(ticketType, numberOfTickets);
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
String orderTotalStr = formatter.format(orderTotalDbl);
```

Then output the `orderTotalStr` (it will have a dollar sign already)

Comment: It seems to be almost working, only problem is, I'm not sure where to insert the code you gave me. For instance putting it inside the println() doesn't do anything.

Comment: Put the code directly before the println(), and then make that last line of the println() statement say `+ "\nOrder Total = " + orderTotalStr));` Remove the line with the `double.parseDouble`

Comment: Just for the record, storing credit card numbers like that is a very bad idea, but I'm guessing this isn't an actual ecommerce application, because that would be a security disaster.

Comment: Haha no it's not an ecommerce app, but yea it will surely be disaster if it was. Thanks again for the help.